# Define $x_0=0$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n-[(\tan x_n-1)/\sec^2x_n]$. What is $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n$ in this example? Relate this to Newton's method.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, numerical-methods

**Define $x_0=0$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n-[(\tan x_n-1)/\sec^2x_n]$. What is $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n$ in this example? Relate this to Newton's method.**

I know that in this case I am trying to find the zeros of the $f(x)=\tan x-1$ function according to Newton's method but I do not know how to calculate this limit, could someone help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you at least compute the first few terms?  The limit is approached quickly and should be a number you recognize.  If you want a root of $f(x)$, what is $\tan^{-1}(1)?$

Comment: @RossMillikan I have already calculated the first terms of the sequence but what I want to know is how to calculate the limit, I know that the roots of $f$ are all $x$ such that $x=\tan^{-1}(1)$, but how do I calculate the limit?

Comment: You should show what you have done on the problem, like finding the first few terms and what you know about the roots of $f(x)$.  At the limit you can replace all the $x$s with the limit $L$.  That gives you $L=\tan^{-1}(1)$ where it is the multivalued arctangent.  The limit is one of the roots of $f(x)$, so you just need to find which one you converge to.

Comment: @RossMillikan I have the following according to what you say: $L=L-(\frac{\tan (L)-1}{\sec^2(L)})$ so $\tan (L)-1=0$ so $L=\tan^{-1}(1)$, and since the starting point of the sequence is $x_0=0$, then I have to find the $L$ closest to $0=x_0$ such that $L=\tan^{-1}(1)$ and this is precisely $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: It is not always true that Newton's method converges to the closest root.  It may not converge at all and if you start near a local extremum the small denominator can send you far away.  Consider finding a root of $\cos x$.  If you start with $x_0=0.1$ you converge to $\frac 72\pi$, not $\pm \frac \pi 2$.  Yes, in your problem $\frac \pi4$ is a root, but so is $\frac 54\pi$.  Once you get close, and you do in a few iterations, you can justify that each iteration gets you closer to $\frac \pi 4$.  I don't know if your class demands this proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $f(x)=\tan{x}-1$ is zero if $\tan{x}=1$, from where we have $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$. That is limit you wanted.